# How can I expose both TCP and UDP on a single port in a AWS EC2 Task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running into an issue with port mappings on my AWS Fargate AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition.  The app inside the container listens for both TCP and UDP traffic on a single specific port.  The AWS docs, however, make note that:

> You cannot expose the same container port for multiple protocols. An error will be returned if this is attempted.

Is there a recommended way to work around this limitation for services that listen to both TCP and UDP traffic on a single port? (Other than just running on an EC2 instance directly).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is not possible, I would check if there is a way to expose two different ports on the application level.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, the protocol is optional as it simply defaults to only accepting TCP connections.

Comment: you are right, i have updated my answer to avoid misleading others

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2020 you are now able to map TCP and UDP traffic to a single port in ECS. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ecs-taskdefinition-containerdefinitions-portmappings.html) has been [updated](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-cloudformation-user-guide/commit/8c1b412c7a95a09784cb390cbe20ce8594dd14d2#diff-1d7d89b5163317a4adef077a2501a959bd8c4e3b6dfe4909f002772986b1c3bd) to remove the warning about exposing the same port to multiple protocols.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Support both TCP and UDP on the same port is still on their road map https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/850. The update you mentioned is meant to support TCP and UDP on different port within one task definition rather than on the same port.